# Spring TestRestTemplate timeout

Tags: spring

When debugging a Spring integration test which uses TestRestTemplate (Note: NOT RestTemplate), I sometimes find the client side of the test times out if I'm stepping through breakpoints on the production code (server side).

How do I change the timeouts for Spring TestRestTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new config class at the top of your test (I called it TestConfig):

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = ..., classes = [YourApplication, TestConfig])
```

then include that TestConfig class
and include a custom RestTemplateBuilder as follows
These can both be inner classes of your test class if needed

```
public static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyRestTemplateBuilder myRestTemplateBuilder() {
        return new MyRestTemplateBuilder()
    }
        
}

public static class MyRestTemplateBuilder extends RestTemplateBuilder {
    MyRestTemplateBuilder(RestTemplateCustomizer... customizers) {
        super(customizers)
    }

    @Override
    ClientHttpRequestFactory buildRequestFactory() {
        ClientHttpRequestFactory result = super.buildRequestFactory()
        // Usually result is a: org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory
        result.setConnectTimeout(100000);
        result.setReadTimeout(100000);
        return result
    }
}
```

Your timeouts will be modified as required.

Bonus:
For normal RestTemplate timeouts you can do:

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        
        // This code can be used to change the read timeout for testing
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
        simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(100);  // millis
        
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: PS you can import the TestConfig instead if you like: @Import(TestConfig)

Comment: could you show how this would look in Kotlin? I would like to try out your solution but I'm struggling to use it in my Kotlin code base.